# Ionic 2 + Mailgun attachments

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email with a picture as attachment. Unfortunately everything works except for the attachment. I look around on forums or other questions as well as the API but I just can't figure it out.

Here's the piece of code for sending the email. It receives an array of base64image strings. The images are shown in the app using the same array so I think that part should be allright.

```
sendAtt(pictures: any[]){
    var requestHeaders = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + this.apiKey);
    requestHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    this.http.request(new Request({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + this.mailgunUrl + "/messages",
            body: "from="+this.sender+"&to=" + this.recipient + "&subject=" + this.subject + "&text=" + this.message +"&attachment="+pictures[0] ,
            headers: requestHeaders,
        }))
        .subscribe(success => {
            console.log("SUCCESS -> " + JSON.stringify(success));
        }, error => {
            console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

Comment: Max post size is 25MB, is your image smaller than that? What do the Mailgun logs say?

Answer (score 0):

mailgun's attachment need to be encoded as multipart/form-data.

So your base64image strings won't work, you need to convert it.

```js
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
  const byteString,
        mimestring;

  if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') !== -1) {
    byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  } else {
    byteString = decodeURI(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  }

  mimestring = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
  const content = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    content[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(content)], {
    type: mimestring
  });
  return blob;
}
```

Now instead of pictures[0] use this.dataURItoBlob(pictures[0]) in your http request.